# Combine Sphinx with MySql Regex?

Tags: mysql, regex, sphinx

I have a mysql query where in I do something similar to:

```
Select FieldX from TableY where FieldX regexp '[0-9] VariableString'
```

The problem is the values in VariableString can contain many different words that have synonyms. I have already mapped these in my Sphinx Index but I can't so substring_index or anything similar to extract. So where

```
Select FieldX from idx_TableY where Match('Bob')
```

Will find `Bob Williams` or `Robert Williams` it won't extract 'Williams' from either.

Mysql *will* 'Williams' for

```
Select Substring_index(FieldX,'Bob ',-1) where FieldX regexp '[[:<:]]Bob[[:>:]]'
```

but won't work on `Robert Williams`.

Is there a way to combine the features of both or somehow have regexp query the indexed full-text instead of just the field itself?

Answer (score 0):

The 'extraction' you talk about, should really just be done in the application itself. Sphinx will return you the full matched text field.

Then the application itself, can extract just that part it wants (similar to your example of using Substring_index)

```
<?php
$r = mysql_query("Select FieldX from idx_TableY where Match('Bob')");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
   $v = preg_replace('/\d+\s+/','',$row['FieldX']);
   print "$v\n";
}
```

or similar. Can tailor the preg_replace match as needed.